# Showing all labels in a horizontal bar chart (Blazor)

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, chart.js, blazorise

I am currently trying to display every label in my horizontal bar chart. It currently looks as follows.

[image: Horizontal Bar Chart]

As you can see the `Measurement-Start` is not displayed.

My code looks as follows:

```
public BarChartOptions GetBarChartOptionsBeginAtZeroHorizontal()
{
    var barChartOptions = new BarChartOptions
    {
        IndexAxis = "y",
        Scales = new()
        {
            Y = new()
            {
                BeginAtZero = true,
            },
        }
    };
```

I am using Blazor with the following versions:

- .NET 8 RC2
- chart.js 3.9.1

How can I achieve it so every label is displayed in this chart?

Comment: Ok, the Blazorise no implement the `AutoSkip` in [ChartAxisTicks](https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise/blob/1cbf8f4ae56016d2041eedb5a29fc8f79b883b4f/Source/Extensions/Blazorise.Charts/Options/ChartAxisTicks.cs#L13). You may look for the JS way to render the chart instead of using the Blazorise component